# Prove a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}^+$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm a CS student trying to get into some deeper math. I started following MITOCW course on Real Analisys, but I'm stuck in one of the exercises from the start of the course. Given the following theorem and the defined function $f$, I have to prove that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}^+$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e., $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is countably infinite).

**Theorem**. Let $q ∈ \mathbb{Q}$ with $q > 0$. Then

1. if $q ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and $q \neq 1$, then there exists unique prime numbers $p_1 < p_2 < · · · < p_N$ and unique exponents $r_1, . . . , r_N ∈ N$ such that
   $$ q = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} · · · p_N^{r_N} , (†)$$
2. if $q ∈ \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{N}$, then there exist unique prime numbers $p_1 < p_2 < · · · <
   p_N$ , $q_1 < q_2 < · · · <
   q_M$ with $p_i \neq q_j$ for all $i ∈ {1, . . . , N}$, $j ∈ {1, . . . M}$, and unique
   exponents $r_1, . . . , r_N$, $s_1, . . ., s_M ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that
   $$q = \frac{p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} · · · p_N^{r_N}}{ q_1^{s_1} q_2^{s_2} · · · q_M^{s_N}}, (‡)$$

\

Define $f : \{q ∈ \mathbb{Q} : q > 0\} → \mathbb{N}$ as follows: $f(1) = 1$, if $q ∈ \mathbb{N}$ \ $\{1\}$ is given by $(†)$,
then
$$f(q) = p_1^{2r_1} p_2^{2r_2} · · · p_N^{2r_N},$$
and if $q ∈ \mathbb{Q}$\ $\mathbb{N}$ is given by $(‡)$, then
$$f(q) = p_1^{2r_1} · · · p_N^{2r_N}q_1^{2s_1 - 1} · · · q_M^{2s_N - 1}$$

To prove that $f$ is bijective I have to prove that $f$ is both injective and surjective. I have some idea on how to go about proving the injective part, but i'm completly lost when it comes to the surjective proof.

For the case $(†)$, $f(q) = q^2$. I can prove by contradiction that $q^2$ is a injective function (using the definition: $f(q_1) = f(q_2) \iff q_1 = q_2$).

For case $(‡)$, my line of thinking is the following (although I don't think it is rigourous enough, or even correct altogether): since each number $q$ has a unique combination of prime numbers $p_1, ..., p_N, q_1, ..., q_M$, and exponents $r_1, ..., r_N, s_1, ..., s_M$, and, since each exponent gets mapped by a injective function either $h(x) = 2x$ or $h(x) = 2x - 1$, and there is no overlapping between the range of those functions (i.e., one produces even numbers and the other produces odd numbers), then each value $q$ is gonna be mapped to a unique value $f(q)$.

I guess my questions would then be:

1. Am in the right track for proving the injective property? Can someone give me a more rigourus proof?
2. How do I even start to go about prooving the surjective case?

Comment: I think you have given a good effort. There might be an easier way, though if youve proven $\mathbb N \simeq \mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Then define the map $a/b \mapsto (a,b)$

Comment: The cartesian product of two countable sets is countable. See here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable. As David pointed out, you just need to be able to represent Q as such.

Comment: There's an easier way: $f(a/b)=2^{a-1}(2b-1)$

Comment: @Sam, i think your relation is not a function, for example $f(1/1)=1$ while $f(2/2)=6$. If the domain would be $\mathbb{N}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}^+$ you will not have this problem.

Comment: @UdiFogiel I'm assuming each rational is expressed in its reduced form, which is unique.

Comment: @Sam, if you assume that, 6 won't be in the image of $f$.

Comment: @UdiFogiel You're right, I was mistakenly thinking about one-to-one functions only.

Comment: Try some small cases and see what happens. For example what are $f(4),f(7/22),f(15/2)$? How can you recover the input from those outputs?